# Private Let / Public Get - Let not visible from within the class

Tags: vba

I've written a class in VBA, with members and properties set up as follows:

```
Private mSomeVar As String

Public Property Get SomeVar() As String
    '...
End Property

Private Property Let SomeVar(value As String)
    '...
End Property
```

Which seems like pretty standard practice - read-only properties with private Let functions so the class itself can modify the value, and I can apply some logic (validation, etc) in the property body while doing so, whilst preventing anything outside the class from changing it.

The problem is, when I try to use the Private property from *within the class*, the VBE tells me that it cannot be found:

```
Private Sub SomeInternalMethod()
    'Compile error: Method or data member not found
    Me.SomeVar = "new value" 
End Sub
```

Why can't I use the class's own private properties from within the class itself? If they're invisible from both within and without, is it possible to use private properties at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't the VBA Me keyword access private procedures in its own module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895633/why-cant-the-vba-me-keyword-access-private-procedures-in-its-own-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem in the Related questions. The `Me` keyword in VBA only exposes the `Public` interface of the class, not `Private`. That seems really obnoxious, but can solve the problem by removing the `Me` keyword (although then I potentially have to deal with shadowing where a method takes parameters with the same name as the property. More needless hungarian notation? Yay!)

[Why do calls to Class Module Private Subs fail when using `Me`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702559/why-do-calls-to-class-module-private-subs-fail-when-using-me?rq=1)

[Why can't the VBA Me keyword access private procedures in its own module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895633/why-cant-the-vba-me-keyword-access-private-procedures-in-its-own-module)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the `Me` object

```
Private Sub SomeInternalMethod()
    SomeVar = "new value" 
End Sub
```